# Grunt runs on port 8000 and I dont know why

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Here is my `Gruntfile.js`.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

  grunt.initConfig({
    dirs: {
      js: ['app/js/**/*.js', '!app/js/libs/**/*.js'],
      jshint: ['Gruntfile.js','app/js/**/*.js','!app/js/libs/**/*.js'],
      html: ['app/index.html'],
      css: ['app/styles/**/*.css'],
      less: ['app/styles/**/*.less'],
      tests: ['test/**/*.js']
    },
    hbs: {
      templateExtension : 'hbs'
    },
    connect:{
      development: {
        port: 9000,
        base: 'app',
        keepalive: true,
        livereload: true
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', ['less', 'connect', 'watch', 'open:dev']);
};
```

When I start the server, it runs on port 8000.  From how I understand it I am specifying the port in the `connect:developement:port` property.  What would make it run on port 8000?
[image]

Comment: In your registerTask you're invoking the default behavior of connect. To reference your specific configuration of connect you need to replace 'connect' with 'connect:development'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try changing the connect postfix to development:

```
grunt.registerTask('server', ['less', 'connect:development', 'watch', 'open:dev']);
```

you might need to specify the options too:

```
connect: {
    development: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            base: 'app',
            keepalive: true,
            livereload: true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didnt know, but 8000 is the default port for Grunt